# Function to test regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing the regular expression exercise questions at the end of chapter 9 in the Eloquent Javascript book. 
- [Eloquent Javascript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html).
A Function to test regular expressions is provided. When I run this function its producing undefined rather than the console.log output expected from the function.
[code](https://repl.it/repls/PeruTepidBytecode)

```js
function verify(regexp, yes, no) {
  // Ignore unfinished exercises
  if (regexp.source == "...") return;
  for (let str of yes)
    if (!regexp.test(str)) {
      console.log(`Failure to match '${str}'`);
    }
  for (let str of no)
    if (regexp.test(str)) {
      console.log(`Unexpected match for '${str}'`);
    }
}

// test for car and cat
console.log(verify(/ca[rt]/, ["my car", "bad cats"], ["camper", "high art"]));
```

Comment: The way you're calling the function, there will be no `console.log()` output. The "yes" strings match, and the "no" strings don't.

Comment: @Brendan: Your question would be epsilon better if you showed what console output you expected.  (Hint: there are several ways the verify() function can return without producing a value...)

Answer (score 2):

You have three `console.log` statements.

One logs the return value of `verify`. You didn't put a `return` statement in that function, so it will always return `undefined`.

One only logs if something in `yes` doesn't pass the regex… but everything in the `yes` array passes it.

The final one only log if something in `no` does pass, but none of the elements in it pass the test.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a default return statement outside the if and for loops. This should give you a successful console log.

```
function verify(regexp, yes, no) {
  // Ignore unfinished exercises
  if (regexp.source == "...") return;
  for (let str of yes) if (!regexp.test(str)) {
    console.log("Failure to match '${str}'");
 }
 for (let str of no) if (regexp.test(str)) {
   console.log("Unexpected match for '${str}'");
  }
  console.log("all good!");
}

// test for car and cat
console.log(verify(/ca[rt]/,
    ["my car", "bad cats"],
    ["camper", "high art"]));
```